# "Compressed folder is invalid" error returning a zip file from a Web API endpoint

Tags: c#, zip, .net-5

I'm trying to compress/zip a Json string to a file and return that file from my method.
When I try to open the resulting zip file I get a message about the "compressed folder is invalid"

```
 public FileContentResult GenerateZip()
    {
        var jsonResult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(GenerateReport());
        FileContentResult outputFile;
        using (var uncompressedStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonResult)))
        {
            using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var compressorStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true))
                {
                    uncompressedStream.CopyTo(compressorStream);
                }

                outputFile = new FileContentResult(compressedStream.ToArray(), "application/zip")
                {
                    FileDownloadName = "TestReport.Zip"
                };
            }
        }
        return outputFile;
    }
```

The above method is called from a WebAPI endpoint.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileContentResult GetZip()
    {
        var file =  new ReportsBLL(_context, _logger, _config).GenerateZip();
        return File(file.FileContents, file.ContentType, file.FileDownloadName);
    }
```

I've also tried the above code using GZipStream instead of DeflateStream.

Comment: Don't use encoding utf-8.  If you are getting G-ZIP from response then just save the bytes to a file.  You are encoding when saving to the file and then not unencoding when reading.

Comment: That is still not creating a valid Zip file. Looking at the header information in the file it is not showing the Zip signature.  I must be missing some piece of the saving as a file process.

Comment: It is not zip.  It is GZIP compression.